# Firebase Cloud Firestore create entry or update if it already exists

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue of knowing when to add or update an entry to a Firebase Firestore database.

Using `doc_ref.set` will add a document if it does not exist. It will also override all of a documents fields if it already exists and set is called.

Using `doc_ref.update` will update fields of a document if the document exists. If the document does not exist, nothing happens.

How do I add a new field to a document if the field does not currently exist, or update the field if it does exist? I could read the database and check if the field exists, and then use either `set` or `update`, but surely there is an easier way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `merge` option in the `set` operation. From the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document):

> ```
> var cityRef = db.collection('cities').doc('BJ');
>
> var setWithMerge = cityRef.set({
>     capital: true
> }, { merge: true });
> ```
>
> If you're not sure whether the document exists, pass the option to merge the new data with any existing document to avoid overwriting entire documents.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, but I wanted to update array field using [FieldValue.arrayUnion](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayUnion), [FieldValue.arrayRemove](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/FieldValue.html#.arrayRemove). Therefore could not use set/merge.

To avoid checking if document exists before update (costs 1 read), I wrapped update statement with try/catch and check for error code 5 (NOT FOUND). In this case, set value instead of update.
Code example:

```
  try {
    await docRef.update({
      arrayField: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...dates),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 5) {
      // Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update:
      await docRef.set({
        arrayField: dates,
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
try {
    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(cred.user!.uid)
        .update({
            "uid": cred.user!.uid
        });
} catch (e) {
    await _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(cred.user!.uid)
        .set({
            "books": self,
            "goods": "good"
        });
}
```